# “Take part” VS “take part in”

Tags: word-usage

> Though it looked as if there would be a race, he did not take part **in**.

Is **in** necessary here, and why?

I see this sentence in the book, but It doesn’t contain **in**.

Comment: Note that the example sentence, as written, is bordering on ungrammatical, or is at least nonsensical—regardless of the status of *in*. *Thought it looked …* has no subject, and if it's a typo for *though*, the part that follows the comma doesn't tie anything together meaningfully. Either the book is not a good example of English, or the sentence has not been accurately transcribed.

Comment: @JasonBassford It is **Though**.

Comment: Then something like this would make more sense: (1) *Though it looked as if there would be a race, he did not **think of** taking part **in**.* (That also preserves the question about *in*.) You can't say that he didn't take part in something that hasn't occurred yet …

Comment: @JasonBassford The race was happened in the past, so the sentence is right.

Comment: The race might have happened in the past, but the sentence doesn't say that. *It looked **as if** there* ***would be*** is a "future in the past" statement. *Looked* is in the past, but, from that relative point in time, it's describing a possible future event.

Comment: @JasonBassford The future of **would be** is base on the past, because it uses **looked**, so the race could still be in the past.

Comment: We don't know if the race ever happened or not. It seems likely, but still uncertain. The sentence is definitely nonsensical. Only something like this would work—and even then, the use of a comma is stylistically questionable: *There was a race, he did not take part **in**.* Or perhaps, drop the first word and comma: *It looked as if there would be a race he **would** not take part **in**.* But I'm not going to debate this in comments any more …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb phrase **take part in** must be followed by an object.

You take part **in a race**; you take part **in a competition**; you take part **in a game**.

However, **take part** (without 'in') does not need an object if it refers back to something already mentioned.

There was **a race**. Did you take part?

You can use the dummy object 'it' like this:

There was a race. Did you take part **in it**?